# GROUP BY and Select Max ID with Two Column Condition

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create chat bot, the logic is there are 2 user type, internal and external, and there are many user internal or external.
When user external send a message, then all internal user can read and reply, so I create logic when a external user send
a message, it will send to id `0` as mark.

```
TBL_USER
userId | name     | userType
----------------------------
10     | user10   | internal
11     | user11   | internal
2222   | user2222 | external
2223   | user2223 | external
2224   | user2224 | external
```

```
TBL_CHAT
chatId | chatFrom  | chatTo | chatValue
------------------------------------------------
1      | 2222      | 0      | this value chatId1
2      | 2222      | 0      | this value chatId2
3      | 2223      | 0      | this value chatId3
4      | 2223      | 0      | this value chatId4
5      | 2224      | 0      | this value chatId5
6      | 2224      | 0      | this value chatId6
7      | 10        | 2222   | this value chatId7
8      | 11        | 2223   | this value chatId8
```

I want select last chat summary for each external user, not sure the last chat from each user is outgoing message or ingoing message.

Have tried:

```
SELECT name, chatFrom, chatTo, chatId, chatValue, 
FROM TBL_CHAT INNER JOIN TBL_USER ON chatFrom=userId 
WHERE chatId IN (SELECT MAX(chatId) FROM TBL_CHAT 
WHERE chatTo=0 GROUP BY chatFrom) ORDER BY chatId DESC
```

Result (not like expected):

```
name     | chatFrom | chatTo | chatId | chatValue
----------------------------------------------------------
user2224 | 2224     | 0      | 6      | this value chatId6
user2223 | 2223     | 0      | 4      | this value chatId4
user2222 | 2222     | 0      | 2      | this value chatId2
```

**Expected** :

```
name     | chatFrom | chatTo | chatId | chatValue
----------------------------------------------------------
user2223 | 11       | 2223   | 8      | this value chatId8
user2222 | 10       | 2222   | 7      | this value chatId7
user2224 | 2224     | 0      | 6      | this value chatId6
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Provide your sample data in textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO form (available for copypasting).

Comment: Does none external user can post a message to another external user? and the same about internal users...

Comment: @Akina just cross internal to external, and vice versa. Can't for internal to internal, or external to external.

Answer (score 1):

You need for that to join the chat table twice

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TBL_USER
>     (`userId` int, `name` varchar(8), `userType` varchar(8))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO TBL_USER
>     (`userId`, `name`, `userType`)
> VALUES
>     (10, 'user10', 'internal'),
>     (11, 'user11', 'internal'),
>     (2222, 'user2222', 'external'),
>     (2223, 'user2223', 'external'),
>     (2224, 'user2224', 'external')
> ;
>
>
> CREATE TABLE TBL_CHAT
>     (`chatId` int, `chatFrom` int, `chatTo` int, `chatValue` varchar(18))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO TBL_CHAT
>     (`chatId`, `chatFrom`, `chatTo`, `chatValue`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 2222, 0, 'this value chatId1'),
>     (2, 2222, 0, 'this value chatId2'),
>     (3, 2223, 0, 'this value chatId3'),
>     (4, 2223, 0, 'this value chatId4'),
>     (5, 2224, 0, 'this value chatId5'),
>     (6, 2224, 0, 'this value chatId6'),
>     (7, 10, 2222, 'this value chatId7'),
>     (8, 11, 2223, 'this value chatId8')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     name, tc.chatFrom, IFNULL(tc2.chatFrom,0), tc.chatId, COALESCE(tc2.chatValue,tc.chatValue) chatValue
> FROM
>     TBL_CHAT tc
>         INNER JOIN
>     TBL_USER ON tc.chatFrom = userId
>             LEFT JOIN
>     TBL_CHAT tc2 ON tc2.chatTo = tc.chatFrom 
> WHERE
>     tc.chatId IN (SELECT 
>             MAX(chatId)
>         FROM
>             TBL_CHAT
>         WHERE
>             chatTo = 0
>         GROUP BY chatFrom)
> ORDER BY tc.chatId DESC
> ```

> ```
> name     | chatFrom | IFNULL(tc2.chatFrom,0) | chatId | chatValue         
> :------- | -------: | ---------------------: | -----: | :-----------------
> user2224 |     2224 |                      0 |      6 | this value chatId6
> user2223 |     2223 |                     11 |      4 | this value chatId8
> user2222 |     2222 |                     10 |      2 | this value chatId7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c360c2aec80f420b4acf41662a1aba5)*

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this answer not solve the issue. I want output like the expected in the question. Is it possible?

Comment: @frianH i changed the answer so that the chatvalue fits

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, chatFrom, chatTo, chatId, chatValue

FROM TBL_CHAT a

INNER JOIN TBL_USER b

ON a.chatFrom=b.userId

WHERE a.chatId = (SELECT MAX(chatId)

FROM  TBL_CHAT c

WHERE  c.chatFrom = b.userId)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'b.chatId' in 'where clause', what's wrong?

Comment: Space between b. And chatId  please check now

Comment: Still same issue #1054.

Comment: It's a.chatId , please check now